# Is there a way to suppress/delay intellisense and user assistance in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've switched to VSCode and I find it mostly pretty good.  However, I find Intellisense and the like more of a hindrance than a help 80% of the time.

As an example, here's a screenshot while editing Python with Pylance enabled.  I don't really need to be constantly reminded of every function's signature and it interferes with seeing the code while writing it.  Not only that, it also often covers up the hyperlinks Pylance generates to point to the source file of the function.

[image]

Is there a way to *suppress or delay the popup's automatic appearance*, but keep it handy, possibly via either hover or with a shortcut?  Failing that, a quick full suppression and shortcut to turn it back via boolean flag in settings would be good as well.

Comment: Search for `delay` in the settings.  There is one for suggestions and one for other hovers.

Comment: Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense (seems the settings you're looking for are described there).

Comment: @Mark looks like bumping up `Editor > Hover: Delay` did what I wanted.  I still get the info, but in this case bumped it up from 300 to 3000 msec and it's much better.  If you write it up (cut and pasting my text is enough), I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mark good with closure.